# Making existing icons flat

Tags: adobe-photoshop, corel-paint-shop-pro

How can I make existing icons flat?  I tried to find any tutorial about this, but there is almost none. Is there anyone that knows about this stuff?

For example:

[image: Original image]

to this

[image: Flat icon]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to GD! It would be most helpful if you could add some screenshots and show us what you have tried and where exactly you get stuck. This saves everybody time, and makes it more likely that you will get helpful answers.

Comment: What do you mean by 'flat'? If you mean 'in the style of flat design ala iOS7, which is a different style than what I have' then the answer is you don't. You redraw them as needed.

Comment: No.Not like IOS7 style.I mean ,like the flat icon packs

Comment: Yeah, there's no one magic technique, it's a case of looking at each icon and then designing a flat icon that gets across the same idea. You'll often need to take a very different approach since you'll need less detail.

Comment: @DA01 I think "flat" is pretty self-explanatory. Just solid colors, no gradients or 3D effects. Possibly a long drop-shadow at max.

Comment: @Claudio the catch is that the term is used in many ways. iOS, for example, is called a 'flat design'. But iOS also uses gradients and other effects.

Comment: @DA01 It's still not the general definition of "flat design" and basically does not count to it. It can be *called* flat, but it is not. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_design

Comment: @Claudio ironically, the article states that flat design doesn't use elements to make things look 3D, but the photo shows material design and iOS...both OSes that call themselves flat design, and both use elements to indicate depth (shadows, overlays, gradients, etc.). It's a poorly written article.

Comment: Actually, I went ahead and edited that part to make it clear that flat design doesn't use those *excessively*--not to imply it never uses them.

Comment: @DA01 Allright, iOS basically is (partly) flat design, but for example the control center isn't a perfect example of general flat design. http://cdn.jaxov.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/How-to-Customize-iOS-7-Control-Center-on-Jailbroken-iPhone.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29058/discussion-between-da01-and-claudio).

Comment: @user26302 if my answer helped, please mark it as the best answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There are no automated tools that could do this (well).

There are a couple simple ways to this:
- Replace existing colors with solid *flat* colors and subtle gradients (see example below)
- Redraw/-create the icon in *flat design* (see icon below)

[image: Icon from Cryten icon pack]

**Example**
Here, for example, the helmet is black, so you can select the outlines of the helmet and replace the gradient with a solid black color. After that you can optionally add a simple (*gradient for the*) "glow" effect.
[image: Flat helmet]